# Best Smarty version for PHP 5.2

Tags: php, smarty

What is most recent smarty version to use with PHP 5.2 ?

I can not upgrade PHP on my server for now. 
My Smarty is too old . I want to get never, but some that runs on PHP 5.2 
What is newest smarty version to run on PHP 5.2?

Comment: Just read smarty documentation. It has a requirements section:http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installation.tpl#installation.requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the following versions required these PHP Versions.

```
Smarty 3.x: PHP 5.2+
Smarty 2.x: PHP 4 or 5
```

Choose as per your PHP version Compatibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Smarty 3.x version. It's on Smarty's website :)
http://www.smarty.net/download